# Should I use XNA to create an elevator simulator?

Tags: .net, xna

I want to create an elevator simulator, just for fun! Will it be beneficial to do so in XNA, instead of a Form application or WPF/ Silverlight?

I want to create a simple animation to show the elevator(s) in action.

I prefer to use a .net language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your experience, I guess.  If you are used to doing Forms Controls and simple 2D graphics perhaps on custom controls, then that could work.

I think a Windows Form approach could be done fairly quickly especially if you were going to use a fixed number of floors and buttons.

You could use standard Controls for buttons, and floor display and get it all up and running using the Form designer.  Are you thinking about graphics for the elevator shaft, the elevator's position, doors opening and closing?

If your priority is button and floor logic, then go for Forms.  If your priority is great graphics then XNA.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make your elevator simulator fully 3D, XNA would be a good option.

If you want to do mostly 2D animation, and "real time" graphics aren't as big of an issue, you could consider WPF.  This would work decently for simple 3D, as well (though you have far fewer options than in XNA).

I would suspect that an elevator simulator would be simple enough that WPF might be an easier, faster development experience than XNA - but it's difficult to know without more information.

Answer (score 0):

though in XNA, you could run it with a xbox controller and wow everyone!